# Как создать массив из рандомных чисел и передать эти числа в функции для решения уравнений

Tags: c#

Мне нужно передать значения в эти функции, и эти значения нужно получать из рандомных чисел массива, я не понимаю, как передать массив в эти переменные( пожалуйста помогите, уже очень долго не могу прийти к решению.

```
public static float PointDistance(PointStruct pointOne, PointStruct pointTwo)
{
    float x = pointOne.X - pointTwo.X;
    float y = pointOne.Y - pointTwo.Y;
    return MathF.Sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
}

public static float PointDistanceShort(PointStruct pointOne, PointStruct pointTwo)
{
    float x = pointOne.X - pointTwo.X;
    float y = pointOne.Y - pointTwo.Y;
    return (x * x) + (y * y);
}

public static double PointDistanceDouble(PointStruct pointOne, PointStruct pointTwo)
{
    double x = pointOne.X - pointTwo.X;
    double y = pointOne.Y - pointTwo.Y;
    return Math.Sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
}
```

Comment: Эти методы не принимают массивов в аргументы, какую именно задачу вы решаете? Что должно делать ваше приложение?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, от вас ждут примерно следующего:

```
var random = new Random();

float x1 = (float)random.NextDouble();
float y1 = (float)random.NextDouble();
var pointOne = new PointStruct(x1, y1);

float x2 = (float)random.NextDouble();
float y2 = (float)random.NextDouble();
var pointTwo = new PointStruct(x2, y2);

float distance = PointDistance(pointOne, pointTwo);
```

Генерируем рандомные числа и на их основе создаём объекты точек.